# Works ascending but why doesnt it print anything decending when a>b (python3)

Tags: input, printing, integer, compare

I am trying to get this to print in descending order when a>b. It works fine in ascending order when b>a but there is no output in descending order when a>b

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a<b:
    for i in range (a,b+1):
        print (i,end=' ')
if a>b:
    c=int(a)
    for i in range (a,b+1):
        c=c-1
        print (c,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language this is but, by inference, surely the second :

```
for i in range (a, b+1):
```

That is, when a > b it Should be something like :

```
for i in range (b, a+1):
```